# Exclude element inside css class

Tags: html, css

I know there is a "not" tag, but in this case I do not know how to apply it.

I want to say anything inside this class

HTML structure.

```
 <div>
     <span></span>
     HERE IS TEXT THAT NEEDS CSS.
 </div>
```

CSS

```
div not:span {
        text-shadow: 1px 1px #000, 1px -1px #000, 1px 0 #000, -1px 1px #000, -1px -1px #000, -1px 0 #000, 0 1px #000, 0 -1px #000;
}
```

Comment: I understand that perfectly Hunter.  I just like learning new ways if they exist.

Comment: div:not(span) is the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite span style with `text-shadow: none`

```css
div {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000, 1px -1px #000, 1px 0 #000, -1px 1px #000, -1px -1px #000, -1px 0 #000, 0 1px #000, 0 -1px #000;
}
span {
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Span</span>
  HERE IS TEXT THAT NEEDS CSS.
</div>
```

Or you can place text in another span and then use `div span:not(:first-child)`

```css
div span:not(:first-child) {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000, 1px -1px #000, 1px 0 #000, -1px 1px #000, -1px -1px #000, -1px 0 #000, 0 1px #000, 0 -1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span> HERE IS TEXT THAT NEEDS CSS.</span>
</div>
```